# (How) Can I push notifications from my Mac notification center to my iPhone?

Tags: macos, ios, notifications

I have a 2015 MBP running OS 10.11, and an iPhone 6s with iOS 9. Can I push notifications from the Notification Center on the MBP to the iPhone? If so, how?

And I mean *any* notification. I'm not talking about synchronizing individual apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `Growl` in your Mac, and install `Prowl` in your iPhone. Then setup the Prowl to connect to your Growl instance with the API. Finally you need to forward all OS X notifications to the Growl.

Comment: > Finally you need to forward all OS X notifications to the Growl.


How can I do this?

Comment: Actually this is possible for those applications that have Growl stub inside. In my OS X applications this ability remains only for Dropbox, iTerm, VLC and Transmission (4 of 86 apps). You can manage framework stub with Growl Version Detective, downloadable from http://growl.info/downloads . However there are tutorials here: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/forwarding.aspx https://www.prowlapp.com/faq.php

Comment: It's obvious. The question is how to do this for all apps and notifications.